# Google Maps Polygon Outer Fill

Tags: google-maps-api-3, polygon

Is it possible to create a polygon with Google Maps API where the polygon is completely clear and outside the polygon is shaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean something like a hole, try the suggestions here

[How to add a "hole" to a Circle Polygon (Google Maps API V3)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9534263/1238040)