# Forcing polygon inside/outside in Google Maps V3?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, polygon

My question is similar to this one on another SE site, which didn't seem to get answered very usefully:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10741/google-maps-js-api-v3-polygon-formation

I'm trying to shade large areas of the globe in Google Maps V3 using polygons.  My issue is that that algorithm decides on its own which part of the map is "inside" the polygon and which is "outside".

From what I've been able to tell, the map always sets the South pole outside the polygon.  Example jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YFJ6a/6/

I'm guessing from earlier questions about filling in the area outside a polygon (eg. [Google Maps Polygon Outer Fill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804830/google-maps-polygon-outer-fill)) that there's no way to simply invert a polygon.  I've had some success in using the method described in the link, combining my polygon with a polygon that tightly circles the South pole:

```
[new google.maps.LatLng(-89.99,180), new google.maps.LatLng(-89.99,-120), 
 new google.maps.LatLng(-89.99,-60), new google.maps.LatLng(-89.99,0), 
 new google.maps.LatLng(-89.99,60), new google.maps.LatLng(-89.99,120), 
 new google.maps.LatLng(-89.99,180)]
```

The path above generates a polygon that covers pretty much the entire globe.  But this is messy and only works if my shape doesn't actually intersect with this polygon, which I can't guarantee.  (It's easy for me to wind up with polygons that cross directly at the pole, for example.)

Is there any cleaner or more direct way to accomplish this?